# WordPress/PHP - Conditional "If" Statement with Custom Field / Author Meta

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need a conditional statement to sit inside my **WORDPRESS LOOP** that reads as follows - this is just an example of what I need, I do not have enough knowledge of PHP to structure this properly:

It should read:

```
if the_author_meta('client_id') = 'custom-value-1' then display the following code
       <div><img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img-id', true) ?>"/></div>
else display nothing
```

The client_id is stored in **the_author_meta**, so the function needs to check the value of client_id in the_author_meta and check if it matches the value I enter e.g. "custom-value-1".  If it matches, then it would display the div code, and if not, it would display nothing.

Can someone show me how to structure this into a proper PHP string please?  I am still learning PHP so this will be a big help in my understanding : - )

Zach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it.

```
<?php 
$client_id = get_the_author_meta('client_id');
if ($client_id == 'custom-value-1') { ?>
    <div><img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img-id', true) ?>" /></div>
<?php } ?>
```

See here for comparison operators

- [Comparison
  Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
- [Control
  Structures](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)

Comment: You'd also need to set the $client_id variable first. $client_id = get_the_author_meta('client_id');

Comment: Thanks all - now that I see what it should look like it makes sense :)